# how to make executable(.exe) using arm-linux-androideabi-gcc?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5, android-ndk-r7

I have one shared library ,Which written in c build using arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler now i want to test my shared library so i  written one sample c which call that  shared library(.so) and i want to make .exe , so when i compile i got the error like this
this is my make file

```
      TARG_OS       = WIN32
BUILDTYPE     = Debug
OS_BITS = 32    

SRC     := TestLSBioCore.c 



OBJS = $(SRC:.c=.o)

OUT         = ./Test.exe

OUTLIB      = 

INCLUDE     = -I../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -I../../include

LIBS        = libLSBioCore.so



# C++ compiler flags (-g -O2 -Wall)
#CCFLAGS    = -O2 -w -ansi -D_POSIX_SOURCE

CCFLAGS     = -O2 -w -D_POSIX_SOURCE

DEFS        =  "-D __MSYS__" "-D__NBISLE__"

#LDFLAGS 
CFLAGS = -nostdlib 
LDFLAGS =-Wl,-rpath-link=../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/
LIB = -lc -lm

OBJECT = ../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o \
../../../../../../../android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_android.o




#compiler
#CCC        = mingw32-gcc

CCC         = arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

#Archive
#AR = ar
#AR = /cygdrive/f/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar

AR = arm-linux-androideabi-ar
.SUFFIXES: .c

default: dep $(OUT)

.c.o:
    $(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(DEFS)  $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJS) 
    $(CCC) -o $(OUT) $(OBJECT) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB)
    #$(AR) rcs $(OUTLIB) $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(OBJS)

depend: dep

dep:
#   makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(INCLUDES) $(SRC)

clean:
    del  $(OBJS) $(OUT)
```

i got the  following error

```
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmple'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fadd'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmpgt'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmplt'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_ddiv'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2f'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fsub'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmpge'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dadd'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpgt'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpge'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dsub'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2iz'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fdiv'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2d'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmpeq'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fmul'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmplt'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dcmpeq'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2uiz'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2iz'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2d'
        libLSBioCore.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_idivmod'
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
        Makefile:57: recipe for target `Test.exe' failed
```

i hope i gave the proper link in my make ,i can;t get what the error behind this,do anyone have idea about  how to make exe using arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.

Comment: For the record, it won't be an .exe. It will be a standalone executable file, but it won't have any extension, as per Linux convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen a complicated way; note that with `ndk-build` you can build an executable much easier. For example, look at the **test-libstdc++** NDK sample.

But using the bare **make** is also possible. You need more libraries though, when you set `-nostdlib` on your command line.

Add `-lgcc`. You may need more libs from `toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google` to satisfy more references.